# How does an array initialization causes hardfault error in STM32 Blue Pill?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, embedded, stm32

I am working with STM32 Blue Pill(STM32F103C8T6) and using STM32CubeIDE-1.11.0, and implementing SPI and USB protocol. Here's my code block which induces the error:

```
#define Read_Size 6743

static uint32_t Flash_Address = 0x08000000;

int main(void)
{

    uint8_t Read_Buffer[Read_Size];         //Instance 1 of using Read_Size
    uint8_t spi_Rxdata[Read_Size] = {0};    //Instance 2 of using Read_Size
    while(1){
       if(Flash_Data_Transmission_Flag == 1){
      while(Flash_Address != 0x08100000){
              HAL_Delay(100);
              for(uint16_t j=0; j<**Read_Size**; j++){          //Instance 3 of using Read_Size
             Read_Buffer[j] = *(__IO uint8_t *)Flash_Address;
             Flash_Address++;
          }
          Flash_Address++;
              CDC_Transmit_FS(Read_Buffer, sizeof(Read_Buffer));
           }
        }
     }
    
}
```

There are only 3 instances of `Read_Size`
If I change the value of `Read_size` to more than `6743`, code goes into `HardFault_Handler()` .
(I found 6743 by trial). I understand that a `uint8_t` array will have size n-bytes, when there are n-values in it, so I am doubtful if it has anything to do with the segmentation fault as the memory should not be exceeding if I define `Read_Size` as `8192`.

Here are my code's section headers for referencing to the memory usage:
[image]

As Shown in STM32CubeIDE after code compilation:
[image]

Ram is around 11KB unused, which can be used to store uninitialized array in the stack.

minimum Heap and Stack memory size defined in the linker script

```
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of heap */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x800; /* required amount of stack */
```

May I please know what I am doing wrong, and how to tackle this array initialization problem to prevent the system going into hardfault error?

Comment: Local variables, including arrays, are usually stored on the stack. Your two arrays take up over 13000 bytes, and the stack is probably a lot less than that. Your arrays are even larger than the available free RAM. Do the arrays really need to be that large? What are you planning on sending and receiving? Can't you do it in smaller chunks with *much* smaller buffers?

Comment: This is stack overflow! Welcome to the site.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes I need those arrays to be that large, but thanks for your suggestion I'll check alternatives 

Comment: @Codo haha! Witty, but noted that, that is indeed my problem!

Comment: Make the two large arrays static  (as @nielsen suggested already) - it won't solve the problem of insufficient memory, but it will at least fail to link rather than run and crash, which is arguably better.  You do appear to have a chunk allocated for a heap that you are not using.  Removing or reducing that may just be enough to make it fit.

Comment: @Clifford , Yeah, I'll reduce the heap size, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have around 11 kB of free RAM and try to use 13 kB. So the hard answer is that you either need to choose a MCU with more RAM or use less RAM.

You can have the compiler/linker help detect problems like this. In this case, the required stack size is set at `0x800` bytes (2 kB) which is clearly not enough to accommodate the two arrays of around 6.5 kB. Hence, in this case, the required stack size would need to be maybe `0x4000` bytes (16 kB) assuming there are no other large variables allocated on the stack.

However, since it is difficult to assess the required stack size reliably, it is normally a better strategy to leave the required stack size "small" (e.g. 0x800) and never allocate variables of significant size on the stack. Instead, make them static:

```
    static uint8_t Read_Buffer[Read_Size];
    static uint8_t spi_Rxdata[Read_Size] = {0};
```

This will allow the linker to take such variables into account when determining if the memory use of the program fits with the available amount of RAM and raise an error if that is not the case.

Comment: thank you for your explaining it succinctly, I'll make note of this. Your valuable answer helped me!